# Is there a way that I can use `mmap` on Darwin with superpages in Rust?

Tags: rust, mmap, virtual-memory, darwin, huge-pages

The [`mmap` manpage on Darwin](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/mmap.2.html) specifies that in order to use `mmap` with superpages (the Darwin equivalent of Linux's huge pages), the `VM_FLAGS_SUPERPAGE_SIZE_*` flags should be used.

I'm trying to use this functionality in Rust, but I can't find these constants in either of the Rust libc versions for Darwin ([i686](https://doc.rust-lang.org/libc/i686-apple-darwin/libc/index.html), [x86_64](https://doc.rust-lang.org/libc/x86_64-apple-darwin/libc/index.html)).

Comment: It's most likely that no one else has needed those flags yet. I'd advocate just submitting a PR to the libc crate.

Comment: [The PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/libc/pull/749) was merged August 30th, 2017.